# Is there a variable that contains the date of the latest windows update

Tags: windows, variables, environment-variables, environment, windows-update

I have an enviroment with about 60 servers. I want to develop a tool where I can see the date of the latest update of every single server.
If I had an environment variable for this, it would be really easy to program a tool like that.

Does anyone know if there's an enviroment variable for this?
Is there maybe an easy way to create a variable containing the date?

Thank you for your help & greetings, Dave

Comment: No, there is no environmental variable for this, as you can see by typing `SET` at a command prompt.

Comment: The `ver` command perhaps?  Not a date, but a version number than can be [mapped to the update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ver_(command)#Version_list).  For example v10.0.17134 is April 2018 Update, Version 1803

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Get-HotFix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-hotfix?view=powershell-5.1)

it's quite robust PowerShell cmdlet, see docs

eg in order to get the most recent hotfix on the local computer:

```bsh
PS C:\> (Get-HotFix | sort installedon)[-1]
```

or write your own PowerShell cmdlet